# Can't install Python package on Alpine Docker anymore

Tags: python, linux, docker, alpine-linux

I have a problem that started very recently. The Docker [Alpine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpine_Linux) Python library is not installable any more:

```
apk update && apk upgrade && apk add python
```

```
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
fetch https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community/x86_64/APKINDEX.tar.gz
v3.14.2-119-g9c4e1aa60c [https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/main]
v3.14.2-120-g90167408c8 [https://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.14/community]
OK: 14943 distinct packages available
(1/1) Upgrading alpine-keys (2.3-r1 -> 2.4-r0)
  0%                                               2% #                                             5% ##                                            7% ###                                          10% ####                                         12% #####                                        15% ######                                       17% #######                                      20% #########                                    23% ##########                                   25% ###########                                  28% ############                                 30% #############                                33% ##############                               35% ###############                              38% ################                             41% ##################                           43% ###################                          46% ####################                         48% #####################                        51% ######################                       53% #######################                     % ############################################OK: 7 MiB in 16 packages
ERROR: unable to select packages:
  python (no such package):
    required by: world[python]

Exited with code exit status 1
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You are trying to use the `python` (alias) library instead of `python3`.

Try to use `apk update && apk upgrade && apk add python3` instead.

Comment: Library? Isn’t it an executable?